# How to filter my data in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, filtering

I have 3 tables:

1. `products`
2. `productcolors`
3. `productbrands`

The relationships between them are:

1. a `product` has many `productcolors`;
2. `productbrands` belong to a `product`.

All `products` are tagged with this dependency: `cviebrock/eloquent-taggable`.

I have used this to render all swim tagged data:

```
$allproducts = Product::withAllTags('swim')->get();
```

Now, I want to filter data with colors and brands, but I don't know how to do that.

Here is my product model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentTaggable\Taggable;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Product extends Model
{   
    use Taggable;

    protected $table ='products';

    protected $dates = ['published_at'];

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date) {
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    }

    public function scopePublished($query) {
        $query->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function scopeUnpublished($query) {
        $query->where('published_at', '>', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function scopeNewin($query) {
        $query->where('published_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7));
    }

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date) {
        return $this->asDateTime($date)->toFormattedDateString();
    }

    public function getproductcolor() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\productcolor');
    }

    public function getproductimage() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\productimage');
    }

    public function getproductbrand() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\productbrand');
    }

    public function getproductsize() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\size');
    }
}
```

Here is my `productcolor` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentTaggable\Taggable;

class productcolor extends Model
{   
    use Taggable;

    public function getproductcolor() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Here is my `productBrands` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentTaggable\Taggable;

class productbrand extends Model
{
    use Taggable;

    public function productBrand() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for your models so we know how your relations are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereHas` and `orWhereHas`

```
$allproducts = Product::whereHas('productColors', function($query) {
    $query->where('column', 'condition', 'value');
})->withAllTags('swim')->get();
```

Comment: i posted my models

Comment: @SidHeart Replace `productColors` with your relation name `getproductcolor` and update the where condition to match your filter requirement.

Comment: can u add view form please

Comment: can u add view form please on

Comment: @SidHeart use a select tag to list your color and brand options. `<select name="color"></select>` and then get the selected color or brand using `request()->get('color')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$allproducts = Product::withAllTags('swim')->with(['getproductcolor' => function ($productColorQuery) {
    $productColorQuery->where('blah', '=', 'blah');
}, 'getproductbrand' => function ($productBrandQuery) => {
    $productBrandQuery->where('blah', '=', 'blah');
}])->get();
```

Comment: can tell me about how can i write form

Answer (score 0):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Product::whereHas('colors', function ($q) use ($colorName) {
        $q->where('name', $colorName);
    })
    whereHas('brands', function ($q) use ($brandName) {
        $q->where('name', $brandName);
    })
    ->withAllTags('swim')
    ->get();
```

Don't forget to define relationships in the Product model:

```
public function colors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Color::class);
}

public function brands()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Brand::class);
}
```

Comment: can u add view form it will post or get i never did this so i don't know thanks Please